# Release dhcp lease after forcing client to disconnect

Tags: wifi, access-point, openwrt, dhcpd

I configured a wifi access point based on OpenWRT to limit the number of clients to 4 at the same time. For that purpose I gave a limited number (4) IP addresses leaseable by DHCP. After a period of time (say one hour), I want to force clients to be disconnected and I change the password for wifi credential but I want to be sure that the leases are renewed for new clients and are not still active for the 4 previous mac addresses.

My first question is how to clear the existing leases to enable new client connections in my case? I suppose that deleting the `dhcpd.leases` file removes the information, but that file is not a kind of config file on which leases are granted or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible to use the OMAPI Command Shell (omshell) to modify the end time of the current lease as described in [this thread](https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/dhcp-users/2010-January/011125.html).

(If this works then if you can provide the whole omshell script then we can flesh out this answer.)

Answer (score 0):

doesn't restarting dnsmasq flush the leases?

If you're changing the wifi password anyway, just change that password and reboot the unit.